# I have an exception in exception handling which is different?

Tags: python

in the last line when `i` was printed the message by using alias it was running fine .for example

```
except insufficient as i :
    print("exception is caught",i.msg)
```

but when I did this

```
except insufficient :
    print("exception is caught",insufficient.msg)
```

it was an error ..why???

````
```class insufficient(ZeroDivisionError):
    def __init__(self,arg):
            self.msg=arg
balance=5000
w=int(input("enter a number"))
try:
    if w>5000:
        raise insufficient("balance in the account is insufficient")
    balance=balance-w
    print("no exception and balance is=",balance)
except insufficient :
    print("exception is caught",insufficient.msg)```
````

Error Log:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ahmod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\hello.py", line 8, in <module>
    raise insufficient("balance in the account is insufficient")
insufficient: balance in the account is insufficient

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ahmod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\hello.py", line 12, in <module>
    print("exception is caught",insufficient.msg)
AttributeError: type object 'insufficient' has no attribute 'msg'
```

Comment: `except insufficient as e` then do e.msg. Also I believe you can use the super().__init__() so that you can use the conventional `except Exception as e` `e.args[0]`. `msg` is not a class property that's why you can't reach it without creating an instance.

Comment: [super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods)

Answer (score 4):

When you do:

```
except insufficient as i:
```

Whatever `Exception` is thrown by the code in the `try` block is assigned to the variable `i` and is made available in the `except` block. So if your `try` block throws an `insufficient` exception then that exception is assigned to `i`. Hence you can refer to `i.msg`.

But since `msg` is a object attribute in the class `insufficient`, `insufficient.msg` evaluates to nothing.

Lastly:

```
except insufficient:
```

Does not make the thrown object available in the `except` block. `insufficient` here is merely a type identifier. So you can't access the `msg` attribute.

Comment: but if I write it as insufficient as i is just another name of an insufficient class ?? so how i is different from class insufficient

Comment: @AbdaalAhmad: `i` is not just another name for the `insufficient` class. You may be mixing things up with the rules for imports or `with` statements. `i` is a name for the caught *instance* of the `insufficient` class.

Comment: `insuffiecient` is the name of the class. `i` is an instance of the `insufficient` class.

Comment: @user2357112 could u please refer some source link of this concept  so that i can understand this concept better